# Regular Expression for data annotations

Tags: c#, regex

How do I write a regular expression for the following

```
at least 6 characters
at least 1 uppercase
at least 1 lowercase
at least 1 number
at least 1 special character ("#¤%&/( æøå etc.)
```

I tried the below regex but it isn't working.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#+-?$!]).{8,}$
```

Comment: In SO you need to prove that you've tried something before asking a question

Comment: Plase show your effort first

Comment: Tried this ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#+-?$!]).{8,}$ but this does not work with \.

Comment: For future - you should *update your post* in addition to commenting. Note that your should be adding actual code (in this case C#) that compiles and shows what you've tried in minimal sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below regex would satisfy all of your conditions,

```
^(?=.{6,})(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?\W).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nR7cO4/11)

```
(?=.{6,})          at least 6 characters
(?=.*?[A-Z])       at least 1 uppercase
(?=.*?[a-z])       at least 1 lowercase
(?=.*?\d)          at least 1 number
(?=.*?\W)          at least 1 non-word character
```